# Update table if query has some value

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I have a query which gives me a value, which is below

```
protected void CmdUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "select mkey from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL where project_id = '" + 
                        ddlProject.SelectedValue + 
                        "' and " +
                        "building_id = '" +
                        ddlBuilding.SelectedValue + 
                        "' and SALES_USER_ID = '" + 
                        ddlSalesUser.SelectedValue + 
                        "'";
}
```

Now what I want is, if query has some value then write the `update....` statement, which I know. If it doesn't then don't update the table.

I want how to check the condition whether query has values or not ?

**update**

My update statement

```
Update xxacl_pn_leases_all set ASSIGNED_TO = '' where mkey = query
```

Comment: Could you show the update statement as well, and show where `mkey` from your query plugs in?

Comment: Please update your question. What database and ORM are you using?

Comment: In addition, please parameterize your query. Currently, it is very unsafe (look up "sql injection" to see why).

Comment: Use a stored-procedure for this logic. Then you can use `IF EXISTS(SELECT 1  FROM  xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL WHERE project_id  =@projectId  AND building_id = @building_id AND SALES_USER_ID = @SALES_USER_ID)
BEGIN
   Update xxacl_pn_leases_all set ASSIGNED_TO = '' WHERE mkey = @mkey
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
 ....
END`

Comment: `mkey` is *not* your primary key, correct?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: it is the primary key,on basis of which I will update my column.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Any other way, can't use SP here.

Comment: @nad: you can use multiple queries with ADO.NET. But that will always be less efficient and more important: prone to race conditions. While you are receiving the result of query1 another user could send an insert so that the table contains that record even if you think that it doesn't exist. In ASP.NET this is likely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
Update xxacl_pn_leases_all set ASSIGNED_TO = '' where your_all_condition_here
```

e.g

```
Update xxacl_pn_leases_all set ASSIGNED_TO = '' where project_id = '" + ddlProject.SelectedValue + "' and "+
                    "building_id = '" + ddlBuilding.SelectedValue + "' and SALES_USER_ID = '" + ddlSalesUser.SelectedValue + "'";
```

above query will update rows which satisfied your condition.

> N.B: Inline query is not good for practice, try using parameterize query instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited as per OP's question edit.**

**Method 1: Front-End**

```
protected void CmdUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "select mkey from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL where project_id = '" + ddlProject.SelectedValue + "' and "+
                "building_id = '" + ddlBuilding.SelectedValue + "' and SALES_USER_ID = '" + ddlSalesUser.SelectedValue + "'";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommnad cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    int mkey = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); //if mkey is numeric
    if (mkey > 0) 
    {
        //Update execution
        query = "Update xxacl_pn_leases_all set ASSIGNED_TO = '' where mkey = mkey";
        SqlCommnad cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    cmd.Dispose();
    cmd1.Dispose();
    con.Close();
}
```

**Method 2: Back-End**

```
UPDATE xxacl_pn_leases_all 
   SET ASSIGNED_TO = '' 
   WHERE mkey IN (SELECT mkey FROM xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL 
                   WHERE project_id = @project_id 
                   AND building_id = @building_id
                   AND SALES_USER_ID = @SALES_USER_ID)
```

Simply execute the above query through your front-end code.

Comment: no this is not the standard way of doing it. It will update the whole table..I am getting the `mkey` in the `query` which is unique for updating the table

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IF EXISTS.` Also it is very important to use `SQL Parameters`:

```
string query = "IF EXISTS (SELECT mkey from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL where project_id = @ID AND building_id =@BUILD_ID and SALES_USER_ID =@User_ID) UPDATE xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL SET .....";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
con.Open();
SqlCommnad cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@ID", ddlProject.SelectedValue);
cmd.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@BUILID",ddlBuilding.SelectedValu);
cmd.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@user_ID",ddlSalesUser.SelectedValue);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `where exists (select 1 from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL where --your query here)`
So it would look kike something like this:

```
Update xxacl_pn_leases_all a set ASSIGNED_TO = '' where exists (select 1 from from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL b where a.id=b.id and project_id ....)
```

Check this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions012.htm)  out.

Answer (score 0):

```
            string _QueryResult = "your query result";

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_QueryResult))
            {
                //Query has no value

            }
            else
            {
                //Query has some value.

            }
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, an explanation is needed to make it to an answer.